# Open new terminal in MacOSX and run node script

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, macos, terminal

I have been trying to figure out how to open a new terminal window from a Node application and run a preset command or script there.

I can open the terminal window:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process')

exec('open -a Terminal ' + process.env.HOME)
```

And this works fine, I have done a bit of research but it seems I can only find examples directed to bash

Could anyone help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to place the commands you want to run in a shell script with the `.command` extension. By default, these files will be opened in the Terminal application on macOS. This is a bit of a workaround, but I think it achieves what you would like to do.

Say we have the file `hello.js` containing the following:

```js
console.log("Hello World")
```

And the shell script `run_node.command`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
node hello.js
```

Running the command `open run_node.command` will open a new Terminal.app instance and run the shell script, which in turn runs the node command. The terminal will close when the script exits.